# Sampling time as an input-simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to make a library of functions that will allow me to parameterize filters and other function. In simulink standard blocks, I am only able to set a sampling time prior, rather than take an input. Is there any ideas on how I can create this? My first approach was to use conditionals and a clock to allow this parameter to exist, but the clock cannot be parameterized either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The typical way of parameterizing blocks is to define their parameters -- which in a Simulink context specifically means data entered into the block dialog -- as MATLAB variables, then set values for those variables before starting the simulation.  But it's not clear if that's what you are asking for, or whether you are saying that you want to change the sample rate of each block while the simulation is running (using an input signal)?  Or possibly you want to have a constant sample rate, but allow the user to specify it as an input signal rather than on a dialog? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, yes, I am trying to change the sample rate of each block while the simulation is running, using an input signal. I.E. If I have a discrete filter block, I would like to be able to change the sampling of this block with a given input signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to write each of your blocks as S-Functions.

If you are using m-code then within the `setup` method you'll need to define the block sample time as

`block.SampleTimes = [-2 0];`

then within the `output` method you'll need to set the next sample time (based on the value of the input signal) by assigning the new value into `block.NextTimeHit`.
An example of doing this can be found here: [A Square Wave with Jitter](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-sfunction-square-wave-with-jitter.html)

A similar thing can be done in a c-mex S-Function by using the [mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/mdlgettimeofnextvarhit.html) method.