# Reproducing a discrete filter block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to make a discrete filter, where the sampling rate can be controlled by an input. I am trying to understand how the discrete filter block looks, "under its own mask." Is there anyway to retrieve the code behind this block so it can be modified for my use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [user-defined function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) as a filter, pick the filter transfer function, translate it into a difference equation (the discrete-time equivalant to the diferrential equation), implement that difference equation in a function and feed the sampling rate as an input (the sampling rate will appear as a constant in your difference equation).

Comment: how does one pick the filter transfer function, is it 'tf'? This is what I tried earlier.

Comment: yes, it is tf. Transfer functions are in the laplace domain (continous domain), you have to translate it to the discrete-domain (Z transform) and then to a difference equation.

Comment: Okay so once I have my tf, is there a function to transfer my tf into a difference equation or must I do it by hand?

Comment: you can do it in steps: transfer function -> z transform -> difference equation, I can't do all the work for you, there are functions for all the steps in matlab, search for: transfer function to Z transform and Z transform to difference equation

Comment: Although this answer describes how you might go about determining the tf, it does not address the requirement of wanting to change the sample rate during simulation.  Using a MATLAB Function block will not work as there is no mechanism for changing the sample rate during simulation.  Only S-Functions can be made to change their sample rate during simulation.  How to do this is described in the OP's other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352543/sampling-time-as-an-input-simulink.  Having said that, having a filter will a varying sample rate seems like a very strange idea.

Answer (score 1):

The block is too complex and has too many options to simply be able to look under the mask. Your best option is to have a look at the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretefilter.html), which does show some detailed implementation of the block in some articular cases to get an idea and then try to recreate the discrete filter you want from basic building blocks, using a constant sample time at first, until you can validate your own implementation against the Simulink library block. Only then, start considering how you will change the sample time. Your main problem though is that the filter coefficients will change with the sample time, so you need to be able to re-calculate them on the fly. It's not an easy problem, I don't even know if it's possible.